# How to refactor code, that has a repeating pattern in Java?

Tags: java

I have a repeating pattern, was wondering how do I refactor the example code below?

two things are changing, first I do a null check on the item, and update its color property if it exists, otherwise set the default color to red.

then a different method gets invoked depending on the item type.

```java
if (item.small() == null) {
    final ModifiedItem modifiedItem = new ModifiedItem();
    modifiedItem.setColor(Red);
    bag.storeSmallItem(modifiedItem);
} else {
    final ModifiedItem modifiedItem = item.small().getValue();
    modifiedItem.setColor(Blue);
    bag.storeSmallItem(modifiedItem);            
}

if (item.medium() == null) {
    final ModifiedItem modifiedItem = new ModifiedItem();
    modifiedItem.setColor(Red);
    bag.storeMediumItem(modifiedItem);
} else {
    final ModifiedItem modifiedItem = item.medium().getValue();
    modifiedItem.setColor(Yellow);
    bag.storeMediumItem(modifiedItem);            
}

if (item.large() == null) {
    final ModifiedItem modifiedItem = new ModifiedItem();
    modifiedItem.setColor(Red);
    bag.storeLargeItem(modifiedItem);
} else {
    final ModifiedItem modifiedItem = item.large().getValue();
    modifiedItem.setColor(Black);
    bag.storeLargeItem(modifiedItem);            
}
```

Comment: Seems that this code snippet is working. What about __moving this question to [codereview.se]__ which is the Q&A site for code-optimization like _refactoring_ ️

Comment: I'm not a java programmer so advice might not be applicable (hence why this isnt an answer), but first thing that comes to mind:
Put them into an array, create a 'Small, medium large' enum, loop over the array and index into the arrays through the enum instead of having 'small, medium, large' accessors

Comment: Extract your logic into a method. Pass the appropriate 'set' function in as an argument, probably as a Consumer..

Comment: You should really replace your `.<Size>()` methods to return an Optional, and replace the `.getValue()` methods with just `.get()`... That would fix all your null checks

Comment: Trying to offer assistance to snippets of code out of context may lead to other problems or a waste of time for all concerned.  I recommend you post a [mre] that more adequately shows what you are doing.  Modified classes with only methods related to this particular question and appropriate data structures should be provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 2 Step refactoring

(1) extract all that is the same for each if-branch/size/check:

- the default modified item is red
- after each size check: (a) if found, the **size-mapped color** is set and then (Red or size-colored) **stored size-specific** in the same(?) bag.

```java
// the default is red
ModifiedItem modifiedItem = new ModifiedItem();
modifiedItem.setColor(Red);

if (item.small() != null) {
    modifiedItem = item.small().getValue();
    modifiedItem.setColor(Blue);
}
bag.storeSmallItem(modifiedItem);

modifiedItem.setColor(Red); // reset color
if (item.medium() != null) {
    modifiedItem = item.medium.getValue();
    modifiedItem.setColor(Yellow);
}
bag.storeMediumItem(modifiedItem);

modifiedItem.setColor(Red); // reset color
if (item.large() != null) {
    modifiedItem = item.large.getValue(); // typos fixed, was small.getValud()
    modifiedItem.setColor(Black);
}
bag.storeLargeItem(modifiedItem);
```

(2) Imagine you could relate color to size and move that mapping to the `getValue()` of each sized field. Then instead accessing fields and call the method on them you would have 3 separate getters for `small`, `medium`, `large`. For example:

- instead of `large.getValue()` this would be a named getter returning `Optional`:

```java
public Optional<ModifiedItem> getLargeItem() {
  if (this.large == null) {
    return Optional.empty();
  }
  
  var modifiedItem = new ModifiedItem();
  // with Blue for small, Yellow for medium
  modifiedItem.setColor( Black ); // for large
  
  return Optional.of(modifiedItem);
}
```

Then you still have to do the not-null-check repeatedly but can store directly afterwards.

```java
final ModifiedItem defaultItem = new ModifiedItem();
defaultItem.setColor(Red);

bag.storeSmallItem( item.getSmallItem().orElse(defaultItem) );
bag.storeMediumItem( item.getMediumItem().orElse(defaultItem) );
bag.storeLargeItem( item.getLargeItem().orElse(defaultItem) );
```

Now your code clearly expresses that always **exactly 3 items are stored** in the bag (either with their respective color if sized-item present, or as default in red).

#### Is that really what is expected?

You will always get a bag with 3 items.
Even if no of the 3 sizes is present at all, then small, medium and large are stored with default-color `Red`.

Comment: This code may fail.  depending on whether item.small() == null) means the item is medium/large (exclusive conditionals) or if it means item.smallHasNotBeenProvisionedYet () (non-exclusive conditionals).  Question is not clear on points like that.

Comment: @Alan Agree ... OP not yet clearly specified that exclusivity. 
Though, as far as the code given (all 3 if-else blocks sequentially), my refactoring proposed is expected to lead to the same result. (Even if the access of fields has changed to an unconventional getter like `item.medium()` meanwhile ️)

Answer (score 0):

The default colour (Red) should be set in the default constructor `ModifiedItem ()`.

Why the test for null on `item.small ()` (medium, large) ?  Perhaps you are making those methods do double duty: return an item and and signal absence by returning `null` for the purposes of this loop?

Might be better to make isNotSmall (), return a boolean and test directly.

Change variable `modifiedItem` to something like `modItem` to de-emphasize it, shorten lines and good stuff.  Meaning remains clear because of the class name it instantiates.  Since it is local to the conditional branches, it can be even shorter like `mod`.

The name `bag` on the other hand should be lengthened and made more expressive since it has a wider scope.

Putting that together we get:

```
    if (item.isNotSmall ()) {
        final ModifiedItem mod = new ModifiedItem (); // setColor (Red) by default.
        shoppingBag.storeSmallItem (mod);
    } else {
        final ModifiedItem mod = item.small.getValue ();
        mod.setColor (Blue);
        shoppingBag.storeSmallItem (mod);
    }
    if (item.isNotMedium ()) {
        final ModifiedItem mod = new ModifiedItem ();
        shoppingBag.storeMediumItem (mod);
    } else {
        final ModifiedItem mod = item.medium.getValue ();
        mod.setColor (Yellow);
        shoppingBag.storeMediumItem (mod);
    }
    if (item.isNotlarge ()) {
        final ModifiedItem mod = new ModifiedItem ();
        shoppingBag.storeLargeItem (mod);
    } else {
        final ModifiedItem mod = item.large.getValue ();
        mod.setColor (Black);
        shoppingBag.storeLargeItem (mod);
    }
```

Now, is the item's size mutually exclusive, as hinted by the usage of size adjectives?  Or not:  the logic is a bit twisted because if an item is large, then presumably two modified items are created: small and medium.  True?

You need to be more explicit in comments or naming as to what something is supposed to mean.  Maybe you mean to have something like:

```
if (item.smallHasNotBeenCreatedYet ()) {
    ....
} else { ....
```

The if parts can be simplified by pushing the `ModifiedItem` creation into `storeSmallItem` code (another, simple, method) like:

```
if (item.needNeedNewSmall ()) {
    shoppingBag.storeNewSmallItem ();
    // method creates default ModifiedItem and then stores it.
}
```

There is a principle that classes should not need to know about other classes internals.  So the call to `item.medium.getValue ()` is tricky at best and might be redundant depending on class extensions.  At the least, push the call into item type:

```
ModifiedItem mod = item.getSmallValue ();
```

or

```
ModifiedItem mod = item.getValue ();
```

depending on meaning of small, etc.

I'm going to stop here because as a commenter said, a minimal working example would clarify some issues.

If you do clarify, add to your question at end rather than write over parts of it, and I might add to the end of this answer.

Answer (score -1):

The only common thing that happens is, in the case where an item's attribute is null, the color is set to "Red", whatever that object happens to be.

Everything *else* is completely different, even the selection of what item attribute to look at.

This is about as simple as it's going to get; creating a method to handle this in a more generic fashion may involve reflection which is unnecessary here.